# I need to mirror a Postgres DB Schema into a React Native Realm Database

Tags: postgresql, react-native, realm

I have created a backend for a mobile app. The database uses Postgres with fairly complex relationships.

Is there a way to recreate the database in Realm? I saw that there was an (enterprise) real-time sync tool that links Realm to Postgres instances, but I'm unsure how to mirror the database in the first place. Do I simply write a schema, step-by-step, on the mobile client to match the Postgres database? The complex relationships involved would make that file very complicated to write.

Answer (score 0):

The [Enterprise Edition of Realm Platform](https://www2.realm.io/enterprise-pricing) contains a [PostgreSQL data connector](https://realm.io/blog/making-postgresql-realtime/) that can perform real-time synchronization between Postgres and Realm Platform, including creating the schema and loading the initial data.

Comment: Link is broken and PostgreSQL data connector is not being distributed.